# Is it correct to say someone is in a certain role?

Tags: prepositions

For example,

"Is Connie in the role of administrator?"

Comment: What is the context? Is *role* in the sense of a character in a performance, the privileged user of a computer system, an organizational position, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct usage.

Figuratively speaking, a role is something you "step into", like shoes. In fact there is an idiom "to step into somebody's shoes", meaning to take over their role (responsibilities) as in a business.

But there can be a slight connotation of temporary-ness in saying "role", so  if you are asking if the person is permanently "in the role", we might just say

"IS connie the (an?) administrator?

To  ask about a temporary role (that is,"filling in for" the usual person), you could say "Is Connie ACTING as administrator?"